# Is any absence of valid http headers should be treated as valid HTTP/0.9 content

Tags: http, user-agent

I encountered a site that for any HTTP request returns html text without any headers. The browser accepts it as ok showing as HTTP/0.9 200 ok in "live headers"

Should any HTTP response that does not start with "HTTP/..." be interpreted as valid HTTP/0.9 content?

UPDATE: Thanks to the CodeCaster's answer, I see that there's a requirement to answer with simple-response in case of simple-request. But may a server respond with simple-response in case of non-simple-request? I could not find any information about this. Looks like user agents always silently accepts simple-responses regardless of the status (simple/non-simple) of their requests

Answer (score 1):

> [RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#page-22) (HTTP/1.0):

> Simple-Request and Simple-Response do not allow the use of any header
> information and are limited to a single request method (GET).

> ```
>   Simple-Request  = "GET" SP Request-URI CRLF
> ```

> ```
>   Simple-Response = [ Entity-Body ]
> ```

> Use of the Simple-Request format is discouraged because it prevents
> the server from identifying the media type of the returned entity.

So yes, but only if the request was a simple request (i.e. only a GET-line).

Comment: Thanks, but does a server forbidden to respond with simple response on a complex request? Looks like browsers accept simple responses without complaining on their own complex requests. Is this correct?